# Filter questions by user

Tags: feature-request, filtering, custom-filters

I've seen that the question of whether we could [filter by user reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152353/filter-questions-by-user-reputation) has been asked before. However, what about filtering by users? Let's say, there are certain users whose questions I really appreciate, or conversely, there are certain users whose questions I sometimes don't want to see. Currently, I can't filter by user the same way I can filter by tags.

Would this be something possible but I just don't know how? Or if not currently possible, could it be a feature to be considered for addition?

I could bookmark those users' profile page to see what they have been posting, but it's not quite the same as a filter for questions. I wouldn't have to open dozens of bookmarked profile pages, for example.

Comment: Your not supposed to target specific users, specifically by showing them appreciation, but every user’s questions are listed in their profile

Comment: These have already been requested and have official responses: [A "friends list" on Stack Overflow would be nice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/886/a-friends-list-on-stack-overflow-would-be-nice) and [Add the ability to ignore users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3353/add-the-ability-to-ignore-users)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that question. What if its not so much a "friends list" as a "follow list"? Friends my have social connotations, including two-way friending.

Comment: Cool, thanks to you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to filter by a single user only, and get the same view as filtering by tag.

To achieve this, follow these steps:

1. Go to the [user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1578867).
2. In the search box on top, append `is:q` to the user id which is already there:

   > [image: appending is:q to search box]
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

That's it. You now filter the questions by that user:

[image: Search results by user]

You can also search by keywords, exactly the same as any other search of questions.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to make the screenshots and write up the answer.